# Facebook link preview will only show host name (even though my fb metadata is there)

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins

I would like to make my Facebook link preview correct (display image, title, and description) whenever I copy and past my web url into facebook to share.

I have included all of the appropriate metadata in my index to make Facebook link previews customized.

```
  <meta property="og:url"   content="http://www.singularity-archlab.com/" />
  <meta property="og:type"  content="company" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Lab for Architectural Singularity" />
  <meta property="og:description"  content="Architecture and design company, technology consulting, and workshops" />
  <meta property="og:image"    content="images/facebook-profile.jpg" />
```

However, it still appears as this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq0nu.png)

The Facebook Developer Debugger has continually confirmed this for me, despite my adjustments.

In my search to correct this, I have been taken down a dark rabbit hole of back end development that I didn't intend. Such as wordpress plugins (https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-link-to-facebook/other_notes/), and converting my code to a wordpress theme to facilitate the wordpress plugins because I built it in webflow.  :/

Do you know of a simpler way to get to the bottom of this? Or must I dive into the deep end of wordpress plugins?

Comment: What URL are you trying to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you share it on Facebook the results are cached by them. That means that if it was wrong the first time then it will stay wrong until they spider the page again which isn't the next time it's shared.

To make it refresh you can use the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](http://www.singularity-archlab.com/). I did this with your URL and it showed that the last time it was reviewed was September 18 at 2:21 p.m. I click the "Scrape Again" button and I'm now seeing it correctly. If you try and share it again you should see it correctly outside of the debugger.

Anytime you make an update to how you want a page to be shared run this debugger and scrape again and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Fencer04. You are right! I also eventually found an article suggesting the same thing. Facebook won't refresh unless you re-initiate it in the Debugger.